# How to write a switch statement for radio buttons

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

I'm working on a movie selector project. I have five radio buttons, after a user has clicked on a radio button, I want to show the movies with that value. I'm thinking a switch statement works the best with this project. I can't seem to get it work, though.

This is one of the radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" id="avenger-movies" name="select-movie" value="avenger-movies">
                <label for="avenger-movies">Avenger films</label>
```

How do I write the statement for these buttons? This is my function thus far:

```
const getRadioButtons = document.getElementsByName("select-movie");
getRadioButtons.forEach((radiobtn) => {
    
    radiobtn.addEventListener('change', (event) => {

        function handleOnChangeEvent() {
            // console.log(event.target.value)
            const inputValue = event.target.value;
            switch (inputValue) {
                // Case..
            }

        }
        handleOnChangeEvent()

    })
    
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="allRadio">
    <input type="radio" id="avenger-movies" name="select-movie" value="avenger-movies">
    <label for="avenger-movies">Avenger films</label>
    <input type="radio" id="hello" name="select-movie" value="avenger-movies">
    <label for="hello">hello world</label>
</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("allRadio").addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
        switch(e.target.getAttribute("id")){
            case 'avenger-movies':
                alert(1);
                break;
            case 'hello':
                alert(2);
                break;
        }
    })
</script>
```

You can use event delegation to handle it, I hope it helps you.